# Migrate from Helm to Istioctl

Tags: istio

I'am running Istio 1.3.5 on my kubernetes cluster. I have installed it using `Helm`. But, this method will be deprecated in the future, so I'd like to migrate to `Istioctl`.

Is there a way to migrate "silently" my actual Istio deployment from `helm` to `istioctl` ?

I read something about `istioctl manifest migrate` but it's not very clear.

I also read that I need to upgrade to 1.4.3 before upgrading to 1.5.x. So I'd like to take this opportunity to switch to the Istioctl installation mode.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not yet a migration path for `helm` to `istioctl`.

There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22874) exactly about that.

> There is not yet a migration path for helm to istioctl, but it will certainly exist in 1.6,which is what this issue is tracking. You can go directly from 1.4 - 1.6 if desired once that is in place. Sorry about some of the confusion, as didn't do a great job around this

So waiting a little bit more might be the easiest solution. As with migration path will most likely offer better support and documentation.

Like You mentioned it is possible to manually migrate `istio` from helm to `istioctl` after upgrading with `helm` first. However this is not a simple task.

Hope it helps.